# Calculating the AnalyserNode's smoothingTimeConstant

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-audio, web-audio-api, requestanimationframe

I am using the Web Audio API to display a visualization of the audio being played. I have an `<audio>` element that is controlling the playback, I then hook it up to the Web Audio API with by creating a `MediaElementSource` node from the `<audio>` element. That is then connected to a `GainNode` and an `AnalyserNode`. [The `AnalyserNode`'s `smoothingTimeConstant` is set to `0.6`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#attributes-ConvolverNode-section_2). The `GainNode` is then connected to the `AudioContext.destination`.

I then call my audio processing function: `onAudioProcess()`. That function will continually call itself using:

```
audioAnimation = requestAnimationFrame(onAudioProcess);
```

The function uses the `AnalyserNode` to `getByteFrequencyData` from the audio, then loops through the (now populated) `Uint8Array` and draws each frequency magnitude on the `<canvas>` element's 2d context. This all works fine.

My issue is that when you pause the `<audio>` element, my `onAudioProcess` function continues to loop (by requesting animation frames on itself) which is needlessly eating up CPU cycles. I can `cancelAnimationFrame(audioAnimation)` but that leaves the last-drawn frequencies on the canvas. I can resolve *that* by also calling `clearRect` on the canvas's 2d context, but it looks very odd compared to just letting the audio processing loop continue (which slowly lowers each bar to the bottom of the canvas because of the `smoothingTimeConstant`).

So what I ended up doing was setting a timeout when the `<audio>` is paused, prior to canceling the animation frame. Doing this I was able to save CPU cycles when no audio was playing **AND** I was still able to maintain the smooth lowering of the frequency bars drawn on the `<canvas>`.

**MY QUESTION:** How do I accurately calculate the number of milliseconds it takes for a frequency magnitude of 255 to hit 0 (the range is 0-255) based on the `AnalyserNode`'s `smoothingTimeConstant` value so that I can properly set the timeout to cancel the animation frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my reading of the spec, I'd think you'd figure it out like this:

```
var val = 255 
  , smooth = 0.6
  , sampl = 48000
  , i = 0
  , ms;
for ( ; val > 0.001; i++ ){
  val = ( val + val * smooth ) / 2;
}
ms = ( i / sampl * 1000 );
```

The problem is that with this kind of averaging, you never *really* get all the way down to zero - so the loop condition is kind of arbitrary. You can make that number smaller and as you'd expect, the value for `ms` gets larger.

Anyway, I could be completely off-base here. But a quick look through the actual Chromium source code *seems* to sort of confirm that this is how it works. Although I'll be the first to admit my C++ is pretty bad.

Comment: Thanks you, sir! I may have actually found a better method of cancelling the animation frame by way of testing your solution! I logged `+new Date` when the audio was paused. Then inside my `onAudioProcess` function when I was looping through the frequency array, I would check if any of the values were above 0. If none of the values were above 0 I would log another `+new Date`. This was helpful to see the variation in the amount of time it took. But it occurred to me that I could simply cancel the animation frame when the audio was `paused` using the same method.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Although, now I'm curious about whether or not I was totally wrong. Hopefully one of the Webkit/Chrome guys will weigh in. I'd love to know how this actually works.